# How to accept a single alphabetical character as input from the user in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and python os my first language i would like to know how I can accept only 1 alphabet letter from the user( meaning the can only enter B OR C OR D  not bc or bd)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `in` operator to check if it's one of `B`, `C` or `D`, and use the `len()` to make sure the length is only 1:

```
user_input = input("Enter a character: ")
if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input in "BCD":
  print("Great!")
else:
  print("Bad input")
```

Add a `while` loop  to request again if it's bad input:

```
while True:
  user_input = input("Enter a character: ")
  if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input in "BCD":
    break
  print("Bad input")
```

---

For the entire alphabet, use `string.ascii_uppercase` or `string.ascii_lowercase` accordingly:

```
import string
user_input = input("Enter a character: ")
if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input.upper() in string.ascii_uppercase:
  print("Great!")
else:
  print("Bad input")
```

Comment: But how can I do this for the entire alphabet

Comment: @HOWEVER answered accordingly.